# About linux v5.4 kernel arm64_memblock_init() / fdt_enforce_memory_region()

Tags: memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel, arm64

**Q**: What is the use of `linux,usable-memory-range` property?

**Background:**

Recently I am analyzing how Linux kernel initializes memory. When I go to `arm64_memblock_init` function in `arch/arm64/mm/init.c`, I meet a function called `fdt_enforce_memory_region()`.The function handles `linux,usable-memory-range` property of chosen node in device tree.

The function call chain is: [`arm64_memblock_init()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4-rc2/source/arch/arm64/mm/init.c#L308) -> [`fdt_enforce_memory_region()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4-rc2/source/arch/arm64/mm/init.c#L296) -> [`memblock_cap_memory_range()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4-rc2/source/mm/memblock.c#L1668).

```c
void __init arm64_memblock_init(void)
{
    const s64 linear_region_size = BIT(vabits_actual - 1);

    /* Handle linux,usable-memory-range property */
    fdt_enforce_memory_region();
    ...
}
static void __init fdt_enforce_memory_region(void)
{
    struct memblock_region reg = {
        .size = 0,
    };

    of_scan_flat_dt(early_init_dt_scan_usablemem, &reg);

    if (reg.size)
        memblock_cap_memory_range(reg.base, reg.size);
}
void __init memblock_cap_memory_range(phys_addr_t base, phys_addr_t size)
{
    int start_rgn, end_rgn;
    int i, ret;

    if (!size)
        return;

    ret = memblock_isolate_range(&memblock.memory, base, size,
                        &start_rgn, &end_rgn);
    if (ret)
        return;
    /* codes below this line make me confused */
    /* remove all the MAP regions */
    for (i = memblock.memory.cnt - 1; i >= end_rgn; i--)  /*-- 1 --*/
        if (!memblock_is_nomap(&memblock.memory.regions[i]))
            memblock_remove_region(&memblock.memory, i);

    for (i = start_rgn - 1; i >= 0; i--)                 /*-- 2 --*/
        if (!memblock_is_nomap(&memblock.memory.regions[i]))
            memblock_remove_region(&memblock.memory, i);

    /* truncate the reserved regions */
    memblock_remove_range(&memblock.reserved, 0, base); /*-- 3 --*/
    memblock_remove_range(&memblock.reserved,          /*-- 4 --*/
            base + size, PHYS_ADDR_MAX);
}
```

After reading [some patches](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9240675/) and [`/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/chosen.txt`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4-rc2/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/chosen.txt),I have learned `linux,usable-memory-range` property is related with crash dump kernel. It should have some relationship with kdump. But why `memblock_cap_memory_range()` **remove** 'memory' and 'reserved' type memory which are marked above the function from 1 to 4, and it only reserves memory from [base, base + size]? I can't understand this.

But from some books, they say "linux,usable-memory-range" prop is the usable range of memory, and `memblock_cap_memory_range()` remove memory beyond this range. If this saying is true,I can understand this. However, as I show above, [some patches](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9240675/) and [this article](https://lwn.net/Articles/705696/) as well as [`/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/chosen.txt`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4-rc2/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/chosen.txt) said the prop is related with kdump.

So, What is the use of `linux,usable-memory-range` property?

Comment: Thanks for prettifying my question! My sincere gratitude.

Comment: Put the code excerpt inside the question. Now it's blurry what you are talking about.

Comment: @0andriy Thanks for your suggestion.I have added the code now.

Answer (score 0):

First some background:

Kexec allows Linux to act as a bootloader and run another kernel (not necessarily a Linux kernel). A user-space tool (kexec from kexec-tools) creates a kexec image including the new kernel and any other binaries needed for booting, such as an initrd/initramfs image, a device tree image, some helper code to jump to the new kernel (purgatory) etc. The kimage also includes information on where those binaries are to be re-located on the new system's memory if needed. The tool then loads the kimage on the running kernel (kexec -l), and when requested (kexec -e) the current kernel will exit, unpack the kimage on memory and jump to the new kernel.

Kdump allows the running kernel, in case of a system crash, to use kexec and jump to another kernel instead of hanging or performing a hw reboot. The new kernel's purpose (also known as crash kernel or dump-capture kernel) is to dump debug data from the crashed kernel's memory and then re-use kexec to re-boot to the normal system (aka primary kernel). The main kernel provides an ELF Core header to the crash kernel and the crash kernel uses it to provide /proc/vmcore as a portal to the crashed kernel's memory. It's a very cool feature that allows for quick recovery from OS crashes (hw reboot can be very slow) while also providing log data for debugging each crash.

For more info on kexec/kdump: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kdump/kdump.txt

Now for your question:

It is very important when we jump to the crash kernel, to preserve the contents of the crashed kernel and not overwrite anything. For this reason in order to use kdump we need to pre-allocate a continuous memory region on the primary kernel using the crashkernel= command line property. The crash kernel will only be able to use that reserved memory region, that means the whole kimage must fit in there, not just the kernel. This also makes jumping to the new kernel simpler since no re-location of the various parts of the kimage is needed, it's already "unpacked".

However the crash kernel needs to know about this somehow, if it re-uses the device tree from the primary kernel nothing prevents it from messing with the crashed kernel's memory. So we have a couple of options:

a) Override /memory node on the crash kernel's device tree so that in only includes the memory region we reserved through crashkernel= on the primary kernel. However when we try to re-boot to the primary kernel we won't know how to restore /memory node to its original value.

b) Use the linux,usable-memory property (see early_init_dt_scan_memory) that will override the reg property of the /memory node and allow the crash kernel to only see the reserved memory region instead. We can then remove that property from the device tree of the crash kernel and re-boot to the primary kernel using the original /memory region.

c) Go with ARM's way and for some reason introduce a new binding, linux,usable-memory-range, that goes to the /chosen node and used for exactly the same thing. Only now since the system has already parsed the /memory node and is ready to use the whole memory, we need to exclude the memory of the primary kernel asap, that's what memblock_cap_memory_range() is for.

Note that it's the userspace tool that adds linux,usable-memory, linux,usable-memory-range and linux,elfcorehdr properties on the crash kernel's device tree when creating the kimage. Those properties are missing under normal operation and you won't see them on /sys/firmware/fdt.

Now that you have an idea of what memblock_cap_memory_range() is all about, in order to better understand the code I guess you should start with memblock_isolate_range(). Have in mind that memory may be split to multiple memblocks, since the /memory node may include an array of regions, or the device tree may have multiple /memory nodes (aka sparse memory layout). So memblock_cap_memory_range() will get called with the start / end address of the crash kernel's reserved region, and will then call memblock_isolate_range() which will walk through the memory memblocks and will make sure that the start / end address are memblock barriers.

As an example think of a memory range 1-10 and 3 memory blocks A[0-3], B[4-8], C[9-10], with crash kernel being on 2-6. In this case memblock_isolate_range() will split A to two blocks A1[0-1] and A2[2-3], and B to B1[4-6] and B2[6-8], and will put the index of A1 on start_rgn and index of B2 on end_rgn. So between start_rgn and end_rgn we'll get A2[2-3] and B1[4-6] that include the reserved region.

The next part of the code will remove the memblocks before and after the reserved region from the set of memory memblocks, so in our example it'll remove A1, B2 and C. Since the memory blocks marked with the no-map flag won't be used anyway, a check with memblock_is_nomap() is done to skip them.

The last part deals with the reserved memblocks outside the crash kernel's region. Have in mind that reserved memblocks marked with nomap will not be present on the set of reserved memblocks / memory memblocks so no special treatment is needed here.

I hope this was more helpful than confusing.